# Explain please sed script

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I can't understand how this sed script works:

```
echo -e "Line #1\n\n\n\nLine #2\n\n\nLine #3" | sed '1s/^$//p;/./,/^$/!d'
```

It suppresses repeated empty lines like `cat -s`
But I have a couple of questions:

1. For what `1s/^$//p`? As I understand it do nothing with the first line even if it empty
2. Is this `/./,/^$/` matches only before first `^$` like `Line #1\n\n` and not matches `Line #1\n\n\n`?
3. Are ranges not greedy by default in sed?

To clarify question 3 I tried next tests:

`echo -e "Line #1\n\n\n\nLine #2\n\n\nLine #3" | sed -n '/#/,/#/p'`

And result was:

```
Line #1



Line #2
Line #3
```

(so, it is greedy)

But when I tried:

```
echo -e "Line #1\n\n\n\nLine #2\n\n\nLine #3" | sed -n '/#1/,/#/p'
```

result was:

```
Line #1



Line #2
```

(now it seems to be not greedy)

Comment: So..  what is the question exactly?

Comment: @DopeGhoti there are 3 questions. I singled them out

Comment: @don_crissti, it's not nonsense, it checks if the line is empty and prints it if so.

Comment: @ilkkachu that's a weird way to do it...

Comment: @don_crissti, in GNU sed, you could use `1{/^$/p}`, but some other seds (like the one on my Mac) may be more picky about requiring newlines with the braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1s/^$//p` prints the first line, if it's empty.

`/./,/^$/` matches lines from the first non-empty line, to the first empty line encountered. It's not greedy in the sense that a regex qualifier is: `sed` can't look ahead to the file or backtrack, so it has to stop the first time the ending pattern matches.

After the ending line, the search for the beginning line starts again, so the next non-empty line again starts the range. In effect, the range matches contiguous nonempty lines, plus the first following empty one.

Since the range is used as `/./,/^$/!d`, all lines not matching it are deleted. This includes the very first line if it's empty, which is why it's explicitly printed by the first rule.

Without the `1s/^$//p` rule, the first line would be removed if empty, even though it's not really "repeating".

```
$ echo $'\nfoo' | sed '1s/^$//p;/./,/^$/!d'

foo
$ echo $'\nfoo' | sed '/./,/^$/!d'
foo
$
```

---

In your test, the range `/#/,/#/` is a bit different since it starts and ends with the same pattern. `Line #1` matches the beginning pattern, (so the intervening empty lines are printed) `Line #2` matches the ending one, (the following empty lines aren't) and on `Line #3`, the range begins again.

In the other one, the starting pattern is `/#1/`, but that's only found once in the input.

Answer (score 0):

ilkkachu gave a great answer, which covered every aspect of this command, including the less-than-obvious need for the first part of the sed string; and including the fact that the "!" character deletes the parts that DON'T match, in practice the repeating blank lines.

Still, it's an odd way to do it, when there are easier options, like *more -s*, or *uniq* available.